# Fire javascript code when download finishes

Tags: javascript, html

I need to update a pair of old classic asp pages— a `search.asp` page that provides a simple form which is then posted to a `results.asp` page.  One of the form options on the search page is a drop down list (`<select`) for the "format".  If the user chooses the excel format the results page just sets the Response.ContentType to `application/vnd.ms-excel` and adds a content-disposition header to set the file name and make it an attachment.  That's it: it's up to excel to then correctly render the html, and it generally does a pretty good job.

All that works pretty well, except for one thing.  The reason for the Excel option is that in this case the users really do want to see as many as 10,000 items or even more for a single search.  They'll use Excel to do some additional analysis on the results.  So the search operation typically takes just over a minute and I can't change that.

The user experience during that minute is less than ideal.  Not only is the user just sitting there with little to no feedback, but there are often enough results that the page overflows the response buffer.  This means the page has to flush periodically, and therefore the file starts downloading right away but the download manager isn't able to provide meaningful feedback by itself.  My mission is to improve the situation.

The first step is to just show a simple `processing...` message on the search page when the form submits, and I can do that easily enough.  In fact, it's been doing this already for the "HTML" format option.  The problem is that when downloading the Excel file I don't know how to tell anything about the download so I can hide the message again, and the existing implementation doesn't provide any feedback on download progress at all.   Any ideas?  If I can just get a javascript function to fire when the download completes I can hook just about anything to that, but I can't even do that yet.

**Update:**
I re-worded the question to try to present the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, browsers don't offer you any hooks as to how far a download has progressed.  In theory, you could do something on the server side and use AJAX to query the server to see how much of the download has been sent, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: No, of course there's not a simple hook :)  If it were that easy I'd have solved this already.  I'm hoping someone's got a trick to work-around the issue.

Comment: Also: for the ajax to work the results.asp page has to support it, and it currently doesn't even come close.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, would it be possible to do this via ajax maybe? ie, user selects the format, query is sent via ajax, and the appropriate document is loaded into an iframe on search.asp for example. you could then pick up the succesful event in your ajax call and appropriately deal with the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the file download as an attachment by adding a header, so that the user's browser remains operational.  I realize this isn't exactly what you're asking for; but if you combine this with the interstitial page you are using for the HTML version, it might be an improvement for user experience.

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls"
```

The user would see the interstitial page with the processing graphic which would then re-post the search form.  This would allow the "Processing..." graphic to display until the page popped up with a download prompt for the Excel file.

**Update:** I tried using an iframe, having the page periodically check the document object and trapping the "interface does not exist" error for when it switches to Excel, but it still locks the browser while the Excel document is downloading in the iframe...  I don't think a pure js solution is going to work.  After that I think the next best avenue to pursue is (unfortunately) Flash.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into modifying your upload method to use something like SWFUpload which allows for JavaScript callback on the code.  Once the file is uploaded (assuming you are storing it), I would look into passing the filename and type to your Results.asp page where it would then retrieve it form the file store.  It's not as secure as keeping it in memory which you elude to in your question; however, would provide a better user experience and may provide the callback solution you need.

http://swfupload.org/

Here's a jQuery plug in example that makes the upload process and SWFUpload integration easy:
http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Where did you get upload from?  No uploads happening here.