# jQuery check when PDF download is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a link which when clicked downloads a pdf file.

Is there a way using jQuery to tell when this has occurred.  Basically I want the link to change from download to please wait.  And when the download is complete it will change to something else.

The main reason is the pdf is generated server side and can take 10 or 20 seconds.

Comment: Any Answer found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to check this; there is no event like `ondownloadready`.

But there are some work-arounds... Check [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk) on stackoverflow.