# IFRAME callback after download completes?

Tags: java, jquery, iframe, callback

Good morning!

I have a java servlet which receives a list of parameters and generates a PDF file for me.

Something like:

```
http://url/download/file?id=123&ext=pdf
```

When I access that URL within my browser window, the file is downloaded.

The problem is that I need to download the file in a hidden iframe, and notify the user when the download completes.

Downloading the file is easy:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                        src:   formURL+'&'+formData+'&docList='+inputDocList.val()
                    });
$('body').append(iframe);
```

Iframe is appended to the body and the download starts. I need to know when the download ends. I already tried using jquery's load event:

```
iframe.load(...)
```

but it wont trigger when my download finishes. I also tried inspecting the DOM of the iframe before and after the download completes, and it appears to be the same.

Is there a way to do this? I need a callback!

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do some callback from the iframe (after finish load) but it doesnt mean the download finished.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982369/jquery-check-when-pdf-download-is-complete) looks like something you need to do. I also did some search and like said in the link i dont think there is a event for this, but you can see some work arounds.