# Can JQuery simulate something on the context menu?

Tags: jquery, save, contextmenu

Is there a way to simulate the event of someone right clicking an  tag and clicking "Save Link As" in Chrome? (This ONLY needs to work in Chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser event when downloaded file is saved to disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the context menu does have its own event, I am not aware that the selection of individual menu items within it can be detected. This is not exposed to JavaScript as many of the options invoke OS-level commands that are out of the security range of JS.

If you are trying to replace the context menu with a custom one, this can be achieved by canceling the default event action and placing your own DHTML menu at the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can not interact with those nor alerts, confirms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware, you'll have to re-build the context menu manually with javascript to put something extra on it.

You'll need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the normal one coming up too.