# After file download redirect to index.php

Tags: php, file, redirect, download

i use this code to download zip file. file is downloading but page is not redirecting plz any one can help.............

```
 <a href="downloading-script.php?filename=1-Adob-Flash-player-11.8.800.zip"><img     src="images/download-button.jpg" id="down-button" /></a>
```

and then
downloading-script.php

```
    <?php
    function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
       {
      if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

         $size = filesize($file);
       $name = rawurldecode($name);

        $known_mime_types=array(
  "html" => "text/html",
         "htm" => "text/html",
             "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
         "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
             "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
              "jpg" => "image/jpg",
            "php" => "text/plain"
          );


      @ob_end_clean(); 

if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

   header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
   list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
       list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
      $range=intval($range);
         if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
         $range_end=intval($range_end);
           }

       $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
   header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
         header("Content-Length: $new_length");
   header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
     } else {
       $new_length=$size;
      header("Content-Length: ".$size);
             }

     $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); 
              $bytes_send = 0;
            if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
          {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
      fseek($file, $range);
       while(!feof($file) && 
 (!connection_aborted()) && 
     ($bytes_send<$new_length)
   )
      {
         $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
       print($buffer);
         flush();
   $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
                  }
     fclose($file);
 } else
   die('Error - can not open file.');
 die();
  }
       set_time_limit(0);

  $file_path='files/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];

   output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');

    ?>
```

i use this code to download zip file. file is downloading but page is not redirecting plz any one can help.............

Comment: 1) Enable error reporting 2) debug your code so you can isolate the problem part 3) plz is not a word 4) Indent your code properly 5) ...........

Comment: The file itself is a response.  A redirect is a response.  You can only have one response per request.  Either the redirect needs to happen client-side or the UX needs to change to not require it.

Comment: You can see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: There is no way to check this; there is no event like ondownloadready.

But there are some work-arounds... Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk] question on stackoverflow.]

Answer (score -2):

I don't see anything in your code that performs a page redirect.

To perform a very simple page redirect, put this at the end of your process:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: This will throw an error after content (such as the entire file) has been sent.  Headers need to be modified before a response is sent, not after.