# How to findout User clicks on open or save Button in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a gridView, which contains link buttons with the names.
In the Code Behind file, i wrote following code for download option.

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
        String x = "~/Nike_folder/MSR/" + e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        string FName = Server.MapPath(x);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/*.*";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FName);
        Response.TransmitFile(FName);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Once user click on any link, browser window will open and ask for open or save or cancel.

I would like to find out whether the user clicks on Open or save.

Is there any way to find this out?

Comment: Where is your gridview code ? And what is the issue with current code ?

Comment: There is no issue in the code? My question is, If user clicks on the link it will open browser window and ask for open the file or save the file. So User click on open the file, i would like to get user is trying to open the file. Otherwise if he saves the file, i would like to get user saved the file.

Comment: Ok ASFIK there is no event that can give you what you want take look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk

Answer (score 0):

supposing you have two button in your gridView

```
var currentButton = sender as Button;
```

and then currentButton.Text or any property

Comment: buttons are not belongings to the gridview. Actuvally it is IE or Crome Browse window.

Comment: so when you click the hyperlink you are invoking jqueryui dialog  ?

Comment: I am not calling any javascript/Jquery.Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/*.*";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FName);
        Response.TransmitFile(FName);
        Response.End();This will take care everything.

Comment: If you can manipulate action click in client side, you can use a hidden field as same as session or response.queryString  to store which button has invoked this action.